# Given IP address and Netmask, how can I calculate the subnet range using bash?

Tags: bash, ip, subnet, netmask

In a bash script I have an IP address like 140.179.220.200 and a netmask like 255.255.224.0. I now want to calculate the Network address(140.179.192.000), first usable Host IP(140.179.192.1), last usable Host IP(140.179.220.254), and the Broadcast Address(140.179.223.255). I was able to find a clean way to do the network address below. I'm able to do subnet calculations by hand, but mainly having difficulties translating that into a bash script. Thanks in advance

```
$ IFS=. read -r i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< "192.168.1.15"
$ IFS=. read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 <<< "255.255.0.0"
$ printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((i1 & m1))" "$((i2 & m2))" "$((i3 & m3))" "$((i4 & m4))"
192.168.0.0
```

Comment: What's the problem here? it looks like you got the expected result.

Comment: I am currently able to only get the network address with the above code. I'm just not sure how to alter this to get the other results I want.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't bother doing this in shell. Use a language (like Python) that has a library for this kind of address manipulation (`ipaddress`).

Comment: Thanks @chepner, it's for a school exercise, but python is also an option. I'm just way less familiar with the language so I didn't look into it. I'll probably be switching to python ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already have the network address. The first host address is just one higher than the network address, which is easy to calculate since you know the low-order bits are zeroes (so there's no overflow to high bytes...)

Then the broadcast address. That's just the address where all the host address bits are set to ones. Those are the bits where the subnet mask is zero. So, to get the broadcast address, invert the mask and do a bitwise `or`. The last host address is just one less from that.

Bash's [arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) supports the same bitwise operators as C and most other languages, so `&` for `and`, `|` for `or`, `^` for xor and `~` for negation. From what you already have, you should be able to produce the missing ones.

(And yes, doing that with the shell seems a bit icky, but if you're going to implement the calculation manually it's going to be pretty much the same in any programming language.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is exactly what I ended up doing, I just had to break it down conceptually and I figured it out.

Answer (score 6):

Calculate network and broadcast with bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$1; mask=$2

IFS=. read -r i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< "$ip"
IFS=. read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 <<< "$mask"

echo "network:   $((i1 & m1)).$((i2 & m2)).$((i3 & m3)).$((i4 & m4))"
echo "broadcast: $((i1 & m1 | 255-m1)).$((i2 & m2 | 255-m2)).$((i3 & m3 | 255-m3)).$((i4 & m4 | 255-m4))"
echo "first IP:  $((i1 & m1)).$((i2 & m2)).$((i3 & m3)).$(((i4 & m4)+1))"
echo "last IP:   $((i1 & m1 | 255-m1)).$((i2 & m2 | 255-m2)).$((i3 & m3 | 255-m3)).$(((i4 & m4 | 255-m4)-1))"
```

Example: `./script.sh 140.179.220.200 255.255.224.0`

Output:

```
network:   140.179.192.0
broadcast: 140.179.223.255
first IP:  140.179.192.1
last IP:   140.179.223.254
```

- A bitwise AND between IP and mask give the network address.
- A bitwise OR between the network address and the inverted mask give the broadcast address.

Answer (score 2):

install ipcalc and:

```
ipcalc 140.179.220.200/255.255.224.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's explicitely a *bash script* that you are looking for (school exercise?), but if not, there's a Linux package called `ipcalc` that does that:

```
$ ipcalc 140.179.220.200 255.255.224.0

Address:   140.179.220.200      10001100.10110011.110 11100.11001000
Netmask:   255.255.224.0 = 19   11111111.11111111.111 00000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.31.255           00000000.00000000.000 11111.11111111
=>
Network:   140.179.192.0/19     10001100.10110011.110 00000.00000000
HostMin:   140.179.192.1        10001100.10110011.110 00000.00000001
HostMax:   140.179.223.254      10001100.10110011.110 11111.11111110
Broadcast: 140.179.223.255      10001100.10110011.110 11111.11111111
Hosts/Net: 8190                  Class B
```

You can prefer the form `ipcalc 140.179.220.200/19`

Comment: This is probably a million times better than any `bash` hackery. If the RedHat network configuration scripts are any example, it takes a *lot* of code to do this correctly.

Comment: Yeah it's for a cruel school exercise, thank you though